# Is there a way to determine the existing partitions in an Azure Table?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'd like to be able to query Azure to determine what partitions are available. There are two different use cases for this.

1) When querying for report aggregation, some of the partitions are based on logging information of things that were done on a specific date. The partition key indicates the data set and the data in it is the operations for that date. I'm aggregating statistical info from that partition into another table. ie: Post processing after the day has completed.

ex: Table name: DailyAggregation
PartitionKey: CustomerID:5,YYYY-MM-DD

I want to avoid trying to query for table partitions that don't exist, and don't want to process all of the data every single day. For example, I have 5 months of stats and have processed the first 4 days but there's a gap of several days or weeks. There's no point to query for data in the partitions that don't exist.

2) Some partitions are based on an identifier that may be deleted in the future. I'd like to write some system integrity code to help me identify partitions that hold data for which the references to them no longer exist so I can delete it. ie: orphan data.

ex: Table name: DailyAggregation
PartitionKey: CustomerID:5,YYYY-MM-DD

The CustomerID is stored in SQL Azure. Let's say the Customer row is deleted. I want to be able to easily determine whether or not any DailyAggregation partitions exist for this CustomerID that no longer exists in order to purge data that is no longer being referenced.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

I would first select the first element in the entire table.  I would do this by not specifying a PartitionKey or a RowKey and "Take 1" to get the first row.

Next I would make another query that gets all the rows that match the partitionkey you just got from the Take 1 query.

Then to get the next start of the next set of elments I would get the first partitionkey that came after the partitionkey you just got.  So if your partitionkey is a date then I would simply add one to the date, so the query would be something like  "PartitionKey >= LastDate.AddDay(1)".  To do this query properly you should convert your date to a long type and pad it so the string representation is the same length.

After that you can just iterate what I explained to get the entire table content without querying any unnecessary dates.

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for, but doesn't help for determining the partitions that exist in order to do data integrity checks. And really my data integrity checks are intended to identify the data that can be deleted from the system. I've updated the question with specific examples.

Perhaps I should simply track whenever I create a new table partition separately? That seems like additional overhead I'd rather not undertake. Maybe I can set a RowKey in every partition and query by RowKey, but not PartitionKey? Thoughts?